# Binding Dropdown in MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind the drop down in MVC In model but i am getting error My code is as follows:

```
private IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> _property;
public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> TestPapers
{
get
{
Controller _controller = new Controller();
_property = _controller.BindTestPaperDropdown(string.Empty);
return _property;
}
set
{
_property = value;
}
```

Can any body say where i am wrong?

Comment: at run time it did not bind my dropdown

Comment: See my answer on [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383105/mvc-3-dropdownlist-or-dropdownlistfor-cant-save-values-in-controller-post/8387828#8387828)

Answer (score 2):

This could also work :

```
<select name="sdfsdf">
    @foreach selectOption in ViewBag['SelectOptions']
        <option value="@selectOption.Value">@selectOption.Text</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Just gotta put everything in the viewbag at the controller
(The example is in Razor)

With aspx it would be something like this i think ... but it's been a while since i wrote any aspx so i might miss something but that's the main idea

```
<select name="sdfsdf">
    <% foreach(var p in products) { %>
        <option value="<% p.Value %>"> <% p.Text %> </option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

Comment: well good solution for MVC 3.0. MVC 2.0 did not supports Razor

Comment: to Use of ViewBag or ViewData is good for application as it is loosely bound data?

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing a link where you can explore various ways to bind dropdown list in mvc.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/ways-to-bind-dropdown-list-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: We prefer answers that include code instead of just a link to another page because links can break at which point the answer becomes useless.